# Download Artifactory artifact using Jenkins and deploy

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, continuous-deployment, artifacts

We have a `Jenkins/Maven/Wildfly/Artifactory` job that builds and deploys `EAR file` on `wildfly` and then in `Artifactory`.

I'm trying to create another `Jenkins` manual job that retrieves a specific build from `Artifactory` and deploys to `Wildfly`.

How do I tell `Jenkins` to retrieve artifacts from `Artifactory`? I'm using '*Copy artifacts from another project*'.

Is there a similar plugin that will help me to download artifacts from `Artifactory`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The artifactory plugin for Jenkins has the option to "resolve" artifacts, i.e. download them from Artifactory.

This may require the Pro version of Artifactory though.

To configure it:

- install the plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin)
- on the job configuration page, enable "Generic Artifactory Integration".
- go to "Resolved Artifacts" and enter the artifacts to resolve/download - the question-mark icon on that page will tell you more about the syntax.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct it requires the Pro version which is paid. 
Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: If you know your artifacts's URL, you can use curl or wget to download it directly in a shell build step.

What I did is create a Python script that uses Artifactory's REST API to query and download the artifacts I need, and then I call that script from a shell build step.

Comment: @tarantoga , can you please share your python script , i require something like this for my project.

Comment: looking for the same script. in Artifactory, there are bunch of snapshots,  how to get the latest snapshot and the latest publication in the snapshot?