# choose artifact from artifactory to deploy pipeline job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Is this possible? Suppose I have 2 jobs. One for building artifact and upload it to artifactory with latest version. And another job to deploy the artifact to the server. But I would like to choose the artifact version. Supose A deploy was made and not working , so I redeploy and choose previous artifact (or the one I want to choose). Is this posible in jenkins in a pipleine project? Like a parametrized build or something like that.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using some jenkins plugin or just shell execution?

Comment: I have installed the artifactory plug in to upload/download. But I would like to know if there is a way to choose an artifac before build starts. With the artifactor plugin I believe the download or upload is inside code.

Comment: Usage of this plugin is mandatory?

Comment: If you know the artifact name, you can convert that into a parameter and pass that in your second job. You can find the artifact name from console output or directly in your slave.

Comment: no  JRichardsz is not mandatory but is the only way I know to do this. What are the other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34781604/3957754

The artifactory plugin for Jenkins has the option to "resolve" artifacts, i.e. download them from Artifactory. But this may require the Pro version with payment $_$

**Download artifact using artifactory jenkins plugin (With Payment)**

- Configure your artifactory plugin

  - https://medium.com/@anusha.sharma3010/integrating-jenkins-with-artifactory-6d18974d163d
  - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in
- In resolve section, you could download your artifacts

**Download artifact using commandline and maven**

- configure maven and artifactory authentication

  - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/artifactory_and_gitlab/
  - https://blog.bosch-si.com/developer/setting-up-maven-and-artifactory/
- download artifact from artifactory

  `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get \
  -DrepoUrl=http://my_artifactory-url.com \
  -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version`

Source: [How can I download a specific Maven artifact in one command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895492/how-can-i-download-a-specific-maven-artifact-in-one-command-line)

Comment: If you want, We can create a jenkins plugin to simple upload and download artifacts

Comment: is this possible? Is exactly what I need

Comment: First, choose one approach and try it. If it works to your requirements, We could start the plugin creation (java knowledge is required). I will wait for your confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

It will work with the pipelin job . I am it in pipeline job only.

Example: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Metadata+Plugin

1. Assume that you have 2 jobs .
2. Job A & Job B. (Both pipeline jobs.)

   ```
        Job A -> Build and push the artifacts to Artifactory. 
        Job B -> Fetch the artifact from Artifactory and deploy.
   ```

   2. Install the Maven Meta Plugin .  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Metadata+Plugin
   3. go to Job B

      1. "This build is parametrerized" checkbox, from the drop-down that appears select the "List maven artifact versions",
         configure the    artifact you want to retrieve the versions
      2. Name the parameter as deploy_version
   4. In Job B - > Select the version & Click Build.
   5. In pipeline script receive the selected version as param.deploy_version.
   6. Since you know the artifact version and artifact URLs . You can use CURL/httprequest plugin in Jenkisn to download the necessary
      artifact from Artifactory (I am using Maven Ansible artifactory
      plugin to download)
   7. Continue with your deployment.

Comment: I´m using a jenkins pipeline proyect, not a maven one, in which the mvn command is executed inside the groovy script in one of the steps of first job: mvn clean compile war:war. I´m looking for a second job that you can manually choose the artifact builded on first job. Is this possible?

Comment: I guess you should push the artifact build during the first job to Artifactory. 

In the second job configure the above mentioned to list the artifacts from artifactory/nexus.
In the second job use the pipeline script to receive the selected artifact and pull it again to deploy it.

Comment: hmmm is this possible with a pipeline job instead maven? the link you said talks about maven: "JENKINS/Maven+Artifact+ChoiceListProvider+Plugin"

Comment: I Need exactly that but for a pipeline job and not maven job

Comment: @yiyito - I've edited the answer now .Hope its clear now.

Comment: I edited question. I did What you suggested but I´m getting that error. I edited and upload image with Jenkins and artifactory configuration as I have now.

Comment: it´s something related to maven-metadata.xml  what XML is this refering to? I have no such file neither on artifactory nor on the script code.

Comment: I also tried with full URL , inside jenkins configuration , to the artifact group as in second image and got other issue.

Comment: hi unfortunately i can't able to see the attached images due to some restrictions.Please double check the configuration and play around with it.  I am sure you can get it.

Comment: Glad that you fixed the issue. How did you resolved using the plugin i mentioned or found any other solutions?

Comment: hehe your solutions was great but I needed more detais to do so. but was good for first orientation. Will mark it as accepted man. thanks